# Python Unicode Handling Errors - How To Simply Remove Unicode

Tags: python, unicode

There are literally dozens, maybe even hundreds of questions on this site about unicode handling errors with python. Here is an example of what I am talking about:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2310: ordinal not in range(128)

A great many of the questions indicate that the OP just wants the offending content to GO AWAY. The responses they receive are uniformly full of mumbo jumbo about codecs, character sets, and all sorts of things that do not address this one basic question:

"I am trying to process a text file with some unicode in it, I could not possibly care any less what this stuff is, it is just noise in the context of the problem I am trying to solve."

So, I have a file with a zillion JSON encoded tweets, I have no interest at all in these special characters, I want them REMOVED from the line.

```
fh = open('file-full-of-unicode.txt')
for line in fh:
   print zap_unicode(line)
```

Given a variable called 'line', how do I simply print it minus any unicode it might contain?

There, I have repeated the question in several different fashions so it can not be misconstrued - unicode is junk in the context of what I am trying to do, I want to convert it to something innocuous or simply remove it entirely. How is this most easily accomplished?

Comment: Remove any Unicode, keeping whatever isn't Unicode? Okay, just change it into an empty string.

Comment: What about learning this article: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html ? It should be pointed too by atleast a quarter of the "dozens os unicode questions" you are talking about, and maybe, just maybe, it can actuallly teach you something so that you might try to keep on coding?

Comment: Why are you even printing the lines, if the content is so meaningless that you can remove characters from it?

Answer (score 12):

You can do `line.decode('ascii', 'ignore')`.  This will decode as ASCII everything that it can, ignoring any errors.

However, if you do this, prepare for pain.  Unicode exists for a reason.  Throwing away parts of your data without even knowing what you're throwing away will almost always cause problems down the road.  It's like saying "I don't care if some of the gizmos inside my car engine don't work, I just want to drive it.  Just take out anything that doesn't work!"  That's all well and good until it explodes.

Comment: BrenBam - I want to calculate sentiment on English words in tweets. Pitching unicode over the side, along with any #hashtag or @username is precisely what I want to accomplish.

Comment: @NealRauhauser: Do you consider café and naïve to be English words?

Comment: @NealRauhauser: By tossing unicode on a character-by-character basis, you will create spurious English words (or invalid English words) out of some non-English words.  If someone writes "élan", you will read it "lan".  If someone writes "cœur" you will read it as "cur".

Comment: +1 for precisely answering the O.P. question - even if it is a questionbotu soemthing he should not do.

Answer (score 8):

The problem can't "go away", the code that can't handle `unicode`s properly *must* be fixed. There is no trivial way to do this, but the simplest way is to decode the bytes on input to make sure that the application is using text everywhere.

Comment: @JeffTratner: That doesn't "resolve" it, that just, well... ignores it.

Comment: Here is a solution for what I was trying to do -  re.sub('\u','',line) nails every instance of a unicode character.

Comment: print str(line.decode('ascii','ignore')) And this one seems to be the right thing. I wrestled with some other decode() things, I guess I am subject to fat fingers & blurry vision this evening.

Comment: @NealRauhauser: Read about what unicode *is* before trying to "get rid" of it.

Comment: @Neal: If your input was not in a strict-ASCII-superset encoding, `.decode('ascii')` not only threw away non-ASCII characters, but also potentially inserted arbitrary characters. For example for UTF-16 and East Asian encodings. For structured formats like JSON and XML that potentially introduces injection security holes. Deliberate Unicode-ignorance is a very poor policy.

Answer (score 0):

as @BrenBarn suggested the result will be spurious english words...

my suggestion is why not consider removing entire word which contains a unicode character 
i.e a word is `space+characters+space` if `characters` has a unicode character then remove all character after previous space and before next space.. the result will be much better than removing just unicode characters..

if you just want to remove names (@username) and tags (#tags) you can use a filter (`[@,#,..]`) instead of brute forcibly searching for all unicode characters..

***I have low reputation so can't comment, so made it as an answer.. :-(***